# How to use precompiled headers with python wheels?

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, precompiled-headers, python-wheel

I'm writing a python packages which I would like to distribute as a wheel, so it can be easily installed via pip install.

As part of the functionality of the package itself I compile C++ code. For that, I distribute with the package some set of header files for the C++ code to include. Now, in order to speed up those compilation operations I'd like to provide a [precompiled-header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precompiled_header) as part of the package. 
I am able to do this if the package is installed via `python setup.py install` because I can add a step after the installation that generates the precompiled header in the installation directory (`some-virtualenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/...`) directly.
But now I can't figure out how to do this when I distribute a wheel. It seems to me that the installation process of a wheel is supposed to be a simple unpack and copy and provides me no way of performing some extra configuration on the installed package (that would generate that precompiled header for example).

As part of my search of how to do this I stumbled across [this](https://github.com/pypa/packaging-problems/issues/64), but no solution is offered there.

Is there any way around this or am I forced to use a source distribution for my package?